# How to make vue set not to monitor data

Tags: vue.js

I used webgl in vue and found that the data written in the return will constantly monitor the scene, resulting in poor performance。

before:

```
data(){
   return{
       //I create a new variable here
   }
}
```

after: （I'm not sure if writing this will make vue not listen to variables）

```
data(){
    //I create a new variable here
    return {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create outside `data` and access it by [`$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options), like `$options.myVar` on your template.

```
export default{
  myVar : 'var',
  data(){   
    return {}
  }
}
```